# Remove parent directories in python build source archive

Tags: python, build, pypi

I have the following setup for my python package:

```
my_package
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┣ setup.cfg
 ┗ pyproject.toml
```

The `__init__.py` is empty, the `pyproject.toml` and the `setup.cfg` contain example output from the [PyPi documentation page](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-pyproject-toml) (content shown below).

Now, for uploading to PyPi and for packing the python project, I run the command

```
python -m build
```

This gives me a new directory `dist` (in `my_package`) containing a `Test-0.0.0.tar.gz`. All this is expected. But when I open the `Test-0.0.0.tar.gz`, I get the following content:

```
Test-0.0.0.tar.gz
 ┗ C:
   ┗ path
     ┗ to
       ┗ my
         ┗ dev-directory
           ┗ my_package
             ┗ dist
               ┗ tmp<some other characters>
                 ┗ Test-0.0.0.tar
```

As you can see, the `.tar.gz` file contains the path on my local machine which is, obviously, not very privacy friendly. I absolutely do not want to upload files containing information about my private file tree structure. And I guess, this is also not intended. Plus, as far as I know, `gzip` does not allow to compress directories directly.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong in my build process?

PS: As you may have guessed by the document tree, I am developing on Windows - which might be important. My Python version is 3.7.1, installed via Miniconda3.

---

## File contents:

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name=Test

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

Comment: Loved the smart use of emojis ,  and . Will use that in my future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my python to version 3.9, now everything works. I tried to find an issue on the official GitHub repository, but I didn't find it. Still, this is a very weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this issue myself and I was curious to know why a Python upgrade corrected this. The issue is a result of a Python bug outlined in the following ticket:

> tarfile: Do not write full path in FNAME field 
> https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85488

This appears to have been corrected in the following Python interpreters:

- [Python 3.8.7](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-7-release-candidate-1)
- [Python 3.9.1](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-9-1-release-candidate-1)
- [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-10-0-alpha-1)

There is some tickets discussing this on [PyPA build](https://github.com/pypa/build), for example https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/255. From my understanding, it looks like the official solution is just to upgrade the Python interpreter. There are hints that a backporting of tarfile should help the module deal with older interpreters, but it does not look like it is planned at this time.